# Error Message When Converting to Grayscale in Python Using PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

So, I've got PIL installed (at least I think properly) to convert color images to grayscale, and when I use this code

```
from PIL import Image 
image_file = Image.open("James.png") # open colour image
image_file = image_file.convert('1') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('Gray.png')
```

IDLE shows me this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Kane/Desktop/huh.py", line 2, in <module>
image_file = Image.open("James.png")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1952, in open
fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'James.png'
```

What do I need to do to fix this? I have Python 2.7, does this make a difference?

Comment: Looks like Image.open wants an absolute path

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the response. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be that the image file "James.png" is not in the same directory as your script, in your example on your Desktop. Is that the case?

Cheers

Comment: No problem, we've all made that mistake. An upvote would be greatly appreciated ;)